# How can I new datetime with 24 hours format in C#.net

Tags: c#, datetime, format, desktop-application

I am developing a c#.net windows application .I want to new a datetime object with 24 hours format So I use below code but it is 12 hours format when I set for example 14:21:30 I want datetime to be 14:21:30 not 02:21:30.
please help me to do this

code:

```
date = dateTimePickerX3.Text.Split('/');
string[] hour3 = textBox33.Text.Split(':', ' ');
DateTime dtv2 = new DateTime(int.Parse(date[0]), int.Parse(date[1]), int.Parse(date[2]), int.Parse(hour3[0]), int.Parse(hour3[1]), int.Parse(hour3[2]), new PersianCalendar());
```

Comment: Why using Text from DateTimePicker? Should have a DateTime object!?!?

Comment: String s = date.ToString("HH:mm"); you can do like this

Comment: Use dateTimePickerX3's Value Property

Comment: I Use dateTimePickerX but It returns date only

Comment: Because it's a "DateTime" picker. This one only choses DateTimes...

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use the `DateTime.ToString` method to get a formatted DateTime string.

```
string formattedTime = dtv2.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Also you should use `dateTimePickerX3.Value` to get the DateTime instance.

Comment: My guess is, since I can only guess here, you are using the default Windows Forms DateTimePicker and there is a Property called Value, which gives a DateTime instance back. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx So if I'm wrong with my guess, I suggest that you provide more information instead of adding more exclamation marks.